# Perl: Changing the name of files

Tags: perl

Everyday the following files appear in my computer (one per day, inside /my/dir/):

```
stackoverflow.20130712_0.log
stackoverflow.20130713_0.log
```

I want to change their name to stackoverflow.20130712 and stackoverflow.20130713, that is, erase the "_0.log" part everyday with a cron job.

A module or script you would recommend me?

I'm on CentOS

Comment: Does your system have the `rename` command? It does renaming using regexp replace.

Comment: it has mv, forgot to write im on centos

Comment: @Barmar: I believe rename from util-linux does not make use of regexp. To add to the confusion, there's also rename from the CPAN File::Rename module which allows for arbitrary perl expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dependencies solution,

```
perl -e 'for (@ARGV){ $t=$_; s|_0[.]log$||; rename($t,$_) }' stackoverflow.*
```

Comment: this is amazing. whats the meaning of the ".*" at the end? :3

Comment: @adriancdperu `.*` tells shell to make all files beginning  with `stackoverflow.` as arguments to perl executable. Try `echo stackoverflow.*` to check this behavior out.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the rename script from CPAN:

http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename

Then you can do:

```
rename 's/_0.log$//' stackoverflow*_0.log
```